# getResponseHeader return null in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, httpresponse

For validation errors in Spring MVC Controller,  i set the custom header **error** to the response Header. I can able to accesss that response Header in Firefox 3.5. But not in IE 8. 
Kindly advice me, the right way to show the custom error message to the Jquery client.

```
    var jqxhr=$.post("saveAcc.htm",{ data: data});

    jqxhr.success(function() { 
        alert("Saved");
    });

    jqxhr.error(function(thrownError){
        fnSetError(jqxhr.getResponseHeader('error'));
        alert(jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); //returns empty
        //alert('responseText '+ thrownError.responseText);
        alert(jqxhr.getResponseHeader('error')); //return null                      
        oTable.fnReloadAjax(); 
     });
```

Comment: I do not know if this helps, but give this a try: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-ie8-problem , this a bug report on jquery $.ajax in IE8, with some possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke the JS error handler function, throw an exception on the server.

Alternatively, you can set the HTTPStatus to 500 or some other error status

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
//response.setStatus(500);
```

But I think your approach is wrong. Validation errors are not application errors, you should handle those in the success message.

```
jqxhr.success(function(data) { 
    if(data['validationMessages'].length > 0 ) {
        //deal with the validation issues
    }
});
```

This may help: http://outbottle.com/spring-3-web-mvc-exception-handling-incorporating-ajax/